# How to read the posted form data to my custom dot net webapi application

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, asp.net-web-api

I have been working on a custom application where I am getting a post from a different web server using a form.  The post is coming from an IIS server.

Now, I need to read this post on my dotnet application (web api 4.0) which is built on MVC platform and running on a different web server (express vs 2012).

Since the request is coming from a different web server all together, what are the possible solutions to this problem?

Your help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you gone through any WebApi tutorials?  That seems like a pretty straight forward WebApi 101 question.

Comment: What do you want to use to receive the post?

Comment: I can can use anything as long as I am able to read the external post. Just a note that the request is coming from different webserver not the express one.

Comment: @VtoCorleone Kindly let me know, I don't find this as straight forward. Let me know if you have some solution in your mind.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api - Read through that guy.  It pretty much tells you step by step what needs to be done on the server and on the client.  Build a test app to get your feet wet with it.

Comment: I guess, the problem is about reading the post from the external webserver like yahoo or some custom post from your apache tomcat to the iis webserver.

Comment: @VtoCorleone  
asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/ this link is very basic one and doesn't help. Let me know if my question is clear to the audience.

Comment: Yes.  It's very basic but it shows you how to post data to a WebApi endpoint and how to consume it.  That's exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: No, The post is coming from the third party or external to the web api. And I need to parse the post and construct a response.

Comment: Ok.  So read that article.  Instead of "you" creating the post, pretend it's the 3rd party creating the post.  The technology is going to work the same no matter who sends the post.  Seriously, did you read that article from start to finish and understand it?

Comment: @VtoCorleone Thank you! the post url was the problem routing in ASP.NET Web API was helpful.

Comment: Glad you got it squared away :)